# Gap because of CSS

Tags: html, css

I have problem on this page:

http://www.endorio.cz/develop/cz/

Green buttons "Detail poptávky" and "Detail nabídky" are aligned with the text on the left, so there create a gap.

You can see it on 5th item: Zvěřínek, Česká republika -> Beroun, Česká republika

How can i align it to the top of each box?

Comment: Normally, you're going to want to post your problem in an isolated code snippet. That way, if the website you're linking to changes, users can still view the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

move your `div class="span2"` into the `header` element like this:

```
<header class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="button green left">Poptávka</a>
    <h3 class="left">keswick -&gt; praha</h3>
    <div class="span2"> // THIS ELEMENT GETS MOVED HERE
        <!--<div class="cicon cicon_rating cicon_rating4"></div>-->
        <a href="user-0" class="button green">Detail poptávky</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

and remove css

```
#section_mainlist .c_mainlist > article .span2 {
    text-align: center;
    /* margin: -111px 0px 0px !important; */ /*<<COMMENT THIS OUT OR REMOVE IT*/
}
```